# Google Rich Snippet Show Time on SERP

Tags: seo, rich-snippets

I have done Google rich snippet work on my [website](http://hubstem.com)  As it shows all good in Google Structured tool but in Google results it does not show anything. 
Please provide me information that how much time google will take to show structured data of my website on SERP ?

Answer (score 1):

The time taken by Google to show rich snippet in its SERP depends on the time it takes to crawl your website once you have implemented rich snippet.

According to Google:

> Once you've marked up your site's content, Google will discover it
>   the next time we crawl your site (although it may take some time for
>   rich snippets to appear in search results, if we do choose to display
>   rich snippets for your site). If you're marking up your content for
>   rich snippets, you can let us know. Google won't be able to
>   individually reply to your message, but we may use the information you
>   supply to improve our detection and display of marked-up content.